# Displaying shows with videos

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, json

My method takes a long time to respond, so I'd like to make this method more efficient. I'd also like this method made with joins.

```
 def all_shows_with_videos
    @arr = []
    tvs = Tv.all
    tvs.each do |tv|
      tv_tmp = {:name => tv.name, :id => tv.id}
      tv_tmp[:videos] = tv.videos
      tv_tmp[:seasons] = []
      season_tmp = {}
      tv.seasons.each do |season|
        season_tmp = {:name => season.name, :id => season.id}
        season_tmp[:videos] = season.videos
        season_tmp[:episodes] = []
        season.episodes.each do |episode|
        season_tmp[:episodes] << {:name => episode.name, :id => episode.id} if episode.videos?
        end
        tv_tmp[:seasons].push(season_tmp) if !season_tmp[:videos].blank? or !season_tmp[:episodes].blank?
      end

      @arr.push(tv_tmp) if !tv_tmp[:videos].blank? or !tv_tmp[:seasons].blank?
    end

    @arr = Kaminari.paginate_array(@arr).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    respond_to do |format|

      format.json {render :json => @arr}
    end
  end
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Iron Man",
        "id": 95,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Trailer 1",
                "site": "Youtube.com",
                "link": "Google.com",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 95,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-05-26T07:05:39+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "How I Met Your Mother",
        "id": 100,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Trailer 1",
                "site": null,
                "link": "google.com",
                "quality": "1020",
                "video_type": "Trailer",
                "videoable_id": 100,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-06-09T10:05:03+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "my tv",
        "id": 124,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 59,
                "name": "Trailer 1",
                "site": null,
                "link": "google.com",
                "quality": "1020",
                "video_type": "Trailer",
                "videoable_id": 124,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-06-20T06:59:32+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Game of Thrones",
        "id": 151,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 129,
                "name": "",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Season",
                "videoable_id": 151,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-02T11:13:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "",
                "site": null,
                "link": "",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 151,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-02T11:13:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 131,
                "name": "",
                "site": null,
                "link": "",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 151,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-02T11:13:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Under the Dome",
        "id": 160,
        "videos": [],
        "seasons": [
            {
                "name": "Season Specials",
                "id": 267,
                "videos": [],
                "episodes": [
                    {
                        "name": "Inside Chester's Mill",
                        "id": 1112
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- Move all logic to models.
- `or` is used for control-flow, `||` for boolean operations.
- `season_tmp` is initialized for no reason.
- Don't resuse variables (`@arr`).
- `!collection.blank?` -> `collection.present?`
- Code is shorter and more declarative if you use functional expressions instead of imperative commands (`each`, `push` and so on).

I'd write:

```
class Tv
  def self.shows_with_videos
    Tv.all.map do |tv|
      seasons = tv.seasons.map do |season|
        episodes_with_videos = season.episodes.select(&:videos?)
        if season.videos.present? || episodes_with_videos.present?
          episodes = episodes_with_videos.map do |episode|
            {:name => episode.name, :id => episode.id}
          end
          {:name => season.name, :id => season.id, :videos => season.videos, :episodes => episodes}
        end
      end.compact

      if tv.videos.present? || seasons.present?
        {:name => tv.name, :id => tv.id, :videos => tv.videos, :seasons => seasons}
      end
    end.compact
  end
end

class TvsController
  def all_shows_with_videos
    @shows_paginated = Kaminari.paginate_array(Tv.shows_with_videos).page(params[:page]).per(5)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render(:json => @shows_paginated) }
    end
  end
end
```